# How do I create partitions in unformatted harddisk space?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning

How to access UN-formatted hard-disk(same in which Ubuntu is installed)space in Ubuntu to create partitions to be used in Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm almost certain you don't actually want to do this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have 50GB unformatted HDD space.Just want use it in my preinstalled Ubuntu by creating partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can install gparted and follow this:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/CreatingPartitions

Or use fdisk on command line:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html